# The sort function does not work properly

Tags: jquery, sorting, dataset

I am using following code to sort items based on their numbers, but it sort them wrongly.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/16n051p8/2/)

```
$('#number').on('click', function() {
                var s = $(this).data('sort');
                console.log(s);
                if (s === 1) {
                    $(this).data('sort', 0);
                    $('.mylist > div').sort(function(a, b) {
                        return a.dataset.sid > b.dataset.sid
                    }).appendTo('.mylist')
                } else {

                    $(this).data('sort', 1);
                    $('.mylist > div').sort(function(a, b) {
                        var temp = a.dataset.sid + " < " + b.dataset.sid
                        console.log(temp);
                        return a.dataset.sid < b.dataset.sid
                    }).appendTo('.mylist')
                }
            });
```

The values are in following order by default, 10000,1500,8900,0,0

When I click once it will be 8900 1500 10000 0 0

If I click again they will be 0 0 10000 1500 8900

The console is as following:

```
10000 < 1500
10000 < 8900
1500 < 8900
0 < 0
10000 < 0


0 < 0
0 < 10000
1500 < 8900
0 < 8900
10000 < 8900
10000 < 1500
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: I guess those `sid`s are strings, not numbers.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I do not have jsfiddle need to create an account

Comment: @GáborBakos they are like data-sid=1500

Comment: use this link http://jsfiddle.net/anoopjoship/16n051p8/. and save the fiddle

Comment: Are you sure you're not sorting _strings_ instead of integers?

Comment: @Daniel, no, you don't need to create an account to make a fiddle and share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
                $('.mylist > div').sort(function(a, b) {
                    return Number(a.dataset.sid) > Number(b.dataset.sid)
                }).appendTo('.mylist')
```

It seems you are sorting by strings, but you would like to sort by numbers.

Comment: Thanks, the demo is included please have a look at that